# how to change date format(Key) in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
days = {1:"MON", 2:"TUE", 3:"WED", 4:"THU", 5:"FRI", 6:"SAT", 7:"SUN"}
```

create a new dictionary like :

```
days_formated = {2:"MON", 3:"TUE", 4:"WED", 5:"THU", 6:"FRI", 7:"SAT", 1:"SUN"}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
days = {1:"MON", 2:"TUE", 3:"WED", 4:"THU", 5:"FRI", 6:"SAT", 7:"SUN"}

days_formated = {k % 7 + 1: days[k] for k in days}

print(days_formated)
```

Prints:

```
{2: 'MON', 3: 'TUE', 4: 'WED', 5: 'THU', 6: 'FRI', 7: 'SAT', 1: 'SUN'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do math operation `nb % 7 + 1`

```
7 -> %7 = 0 -> +1 = 1
1 -> %7 = 1 -> +1 = 2  

result = {k % 7 + 1: v for k, v in days.items()}
print(result)  # {2: "MON", 3: "TUE", 4: "WED", 5: "THU", 6: "FRI", 7: "SAT", 1: "SUN"}
```